# Conversión de datos automáticos tras ejecutar una consulta en Sql server en Python

Tags: python, sql-server

Tengo un error en una consulta de Sql server al tratar de seleccionar un dato en específico me muestra el siguiente error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '100-a13' o data type int.

Tras una larga investigación, descubrí que hay una conversión llamada implícitas. 
Las conversiones implícitas no son visibles para el usuario. SQL Server convierte automáticamente los datos de un tipo de datos al otro. Por ejemplo, cuando se comparan `smallint` con `int`, antes de realizar la operación, `smallint` se convierte implícitamente al tipo `int`.

En mi caso, tengo un dato `nvarchar`, y al ejecutar la consulta el sistema me convierte el dato a tipo `int` generando el error mencionado.

Mi duda es ¿cómo puedo evitar que el sistema me cambie el tipo de dato automático al ejecutar el query?

Código:

```
ver="100-a13"`
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=DESKTOP-ATOSSK5\LIUS24;'
                  'Database=data_SMD;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''select Perfil  from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = '''+ver+ ''' ''')
copy_perfil=[row[0]for row in cursor.fetchall()]
print(copy_perfil)
```

Comment: El problema no está en la conversión implícita, sino que estás comparando un numérico ( `Model`) con un varchar (`Ver`).

Comment: en la base de datos el tipo de dato de todoss estan en varchar menos el id

Comment: Verifica la sentencia `select Perfil  from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = '100-a13'` directamente en SQL ¿funciona?

Comment: si pongo el query directo asi como tu dices si funciona pero si lo hago con una variable: ver ="100-a13" no funciona y me marca el error

Comment: Espera.. la cadena SQL me parece mal formateada, tienes triple comilla simple de apertura y cierre?, prueba: `'select Perfil  from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = '''+ver+ ''' '`.

Comment: creo que el problema es que "100-a13" debe estar entre comillas simples al momento de ejecutar el query, intenta `cursor.execute(f"select Perfil  from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = '{var}')`, eso deberia de funcionar

Comment: Eso mismo iba a decir, te falta las comillas, puedes probar lo que dice @LuisAlejandro o directamente `cursor.execute('''select Perfil  from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = "'''+ver+ '''" ''')`

Comment: @LuisAlejandro, TitoOrt. Sigue saliendo el mismo Error :                                                 pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '100-07365' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en la forma de declarar la sintaxis en la condicion where utilizando las comillas y el string en medio de ellas.

```
sql ="select Perfil from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model=" + "'" + ver + "'"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: No se entiende, ¿esto es una respuesta?

Comment: asi es, el error esta en la sintaxis en la condicon where

Comment: Entonces 2 recomendaciones: marcala como aceptada y por favor edita y agrega la explicación respectiva

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltan las comillas en la SQL para encapsular el valor de `ver`, aunque para que sea más claro el código, yo lo cambiaría por algo tipo template en python:

```
cursor.execute("select Perfil from SMD.dbo.Modelos where Model = '%s'" % ver)
```